# How to do conclude a treatment works when sample size is small with large STD and small effective value

Tags: sample-size, ab-test

I have a data which
population is 3000;
mean is 16;
stdev is 44;

I want to have a test case to check if the mean can be improved to 16.5 or not.
After the calculation, I was told the required sample size is 247K which I can't afford.
How can I deal with this situation?

Thanks

---

To provide more context, I want to check whether a treatment works on a focus group. The large standard deviation with small effective size (expected improvement) make it hard to make conclusions. Is there any method to make the conclusion more solid? What I can think is:

1. Repeat the test.
   However, I may need to repeat it > 100 times
2. Conduct the test on similar focus groups
3. Check other metrics such as action rate (check whether they visit again instead of visiting duration)
4. Conduct the test on different focus group (divided by a continuous variable) and check which focus group is more sensitive to the treatment
5. Split the focus population into 4 groups with (0 treatment, standard treatment, double-magnitude treatment, triple-magnitude treatment) and check the correlation.

Please advice if the above approaches make sense or any other approaches I should try? Many thanks

Comment: Wait... your population of interest is of size 3000? And you know the population's mean and SD, 16 and 44? And you want to do something on this *whole population*, and then determine what your sample size should be to estimate accurately if your treatment had any effect on the *population*? Or are you referring to treating a *sample* from this population?

Comment: I don't understand what you're attempting well enough to offer any advice. Is it the case that you have a population of 3,000 and you want to randomly divided into two groups, treat one group, and then see if this treatment has caused an increase on variable x (from 16 to 16.5)?

Comment: @num_39, yes, and I want to know if splitting into two group is enough for me to make any conclusion. The calculation tells I need much more data sample to do so and I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: @user2974951, yes, 3000 is the whole population of the interest group. And I want to determine the minimum sample size to conduct the test

Comment: Are all of the individual values greater than or equal to 0? I wonder if you have a lot of skew in the data and whether some type of data transformation might help somewhat.

Comment: Hi @EdM, you are right, the data is quite skewed: 60% of data are zero (no action in the next month); Individual values can be greater than or equal 0.
Is there any data transformation technique you would advice? Many thanks

Comment: Plus, the data have some very large outliers (both positive and negative)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, you're trying to do power calculations for an experiment where you randomly assign half of a population of 3,000 to the control group and half of the population to a treatment group.

You want to test a superiority hypothesis:

$$
H_0: \mu_a - \mu_b \le 0.5 \\
H_1: \mu_a - \mu_b > 0.5
$$

You already know the mean and the standard deviation. The other thing you have to estimate is the effect size. If the effect size is 0.5, then your hypothesis is true. So the effect size will need to be larger than 0.5. If it's significantly larger, then you'll have more power. If it's small, though, you'll have limited power to reject the null even if the null is false.

[This calculator](http://powerandsamplesize.com/Calculators/Compare-2-Means/2-Sample-Non-Inferiority-or-Superiority) should give you what you need. Of course, in your case the sample size is fixed at 1500 per group. Here are two quick examples. So if the effect is 2, i.e. the treatment group mean is 18 after the experiment, then you'll only have power of 24 percent.

Taking the R code from the calculator linked above.

```
muA=16
muB=20
delta=0.5
kappa=1
sd=44
alpha=0.05
beta=0.20
nB = 1500
z=(muA-muB + delta)/(sd*sqrt((1+1/kappa)/nB))
(Power=pnorm(z-qnorm(1-alpha))+pnorm(-z-qnorm(1-alpha)))
```

However, if the effect size is 4 (means of 16 for control but 20 for treatment), then you'll have 70 percent power. So as is often the case for power calculations, it really depends on the effect size, and with the sample size you have, you're unlikely to be able to detect a small effect.

(Do let me know if I've misunderstood anything here.)

(Edited to correct error in code and sample size.)

Comment: Thanks @num_39, If the effective size is just around 0.5 (the expected target), which already means a lot to the business. However, the power will be too low. Is there any advice I can do to make the conclusion more concrete? One I can think about is to repeat the test, however, I may need to repeat 100 times which is not very actionable. Please help advice any thing I can do. Thanks

Comment: Typically, a superiority test requires significant more power than a test that the null is less than or equal to zero. In this case, since the standard deviation is so large, it doesn't actually make much difference. If the actual effect is 0.5, then your power is only ~10 percent. Repeated tests could be an option but I don't think I know enough about your case to say more.