# What's the null hypothesis of A/B test following a sample size calculation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design

I have some confusion around what the null hypothesis should be for an A/B test. When we decide to do an A/B test and proceed to perform a sample size calculation. Let's say we work with the following assumptions, a conversion baseline of 2% and a relative MDE of 50% (80% power, 5% alpha, 1 sided test) and use something like the Evan Miller miller sample calculator to find that the minimum sample size per variant is 3292.

Is the null hypothesis in this case:

1. The difference between our treatment and control is less than 50%
2. The difference between our treatment and control is equal to 0%

The reason I am asking is I have seen multiple A/B tests at our workplace conducted where a test is considered as a "success" when a statistically significant result is found even if the relative lift is lower than what the MDE used to calculate the experiment sample size is, when I was under the impression that a test should be considered as rejecting the null hypothesis if and only if the lift is at least higher than the MDE and is statistically significant.

Is this correct?

Comment: It depends. You can make the null whatever you want. Typically, the null is that the effect is zero. You could also use a non-inferiority test such that then null is that the effect is smaller than a certain level. The key thing is you need to find the power for the null hypothesis that you're interested in.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568263/how-to-do-conclude-a-treatment-works-when-sample-size-is-small-with-large-std-an/568295#568295

Comment: What was the hypothesis that was used when the sample size was calculated?